# absolute positioned element over relative positioned div in Chrome

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-position

I found a difference in terms of how Chrome displays an absolute positioned element over a relative positioned div

Here is some markup:

```
<div id="maincontent">
<table id="mainTable">
   <tr class="menuRow">
       <td >
            <div id="menu">
                <ul id="panel">
                    <li>Option 1</li>                                     
                    <li>Option 2</li>                                     
                    <li>Option 3</li>                                     
                </ul>    
            </div>
     </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="contentRow">
            <div id="content" >

            </div>
       </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
#maincontent { width: 100%; }
#mainTable { width: 100%; }
#menu { position: fixed; background-color: green; 
width: 30px; height: 30px; cursor:     pointer; }
#panel{ position: absolute; height: 150px; width: 100px;
 background-color: red;     display:none; z-index:10; }
#content { margin-top: 30px; height: 300px; width:300px;
 background-color: #00F; position:relative;}​
```

I put together a sample [here](http://jsfiddle.net/sU66E/1/) that shows my problem. (If you move the mouse over the green box the red "menu" is shown)

In IE and Firefox I see it correctly over the blue content. In Chrome the "menu" is shown behind content. Is there any way to make this work for Chrome?

Thank you very much, any feedback is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup, up the z-index on `#menu`:

```
#menu { 
    position: fixed; 
    background-color: green; 
    width: 30px; 
    height: 30px; 
    cursor: pointer; 
    z-index: 9999;
 }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Ezn4v/

Answer (score 1):

Lower the index of the blue content div:

`#content { margin-top: 30px; height: 300px; width:300px; background-color: #00F; position:relative; z-index: -1;}​`

Or raise the index of your menu:

`#menu { position: fixed; background-color: green; width: 30px; height: 30px; cursor: pointer; z-index: 1;}`

Comment: That then places the blue box behind the page itself, so that wouldn't work.

Comment: `z-index` doesn't legally allow negative values

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the **z-index** for parent

```
#menu {z-index:11 };
```

[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/sU66E/3/)

Answer (score 1):

Just add a z-index to the menu, then it will work correctly for everyone.

```
#menu {z-index:2; position: fixed; background-color: green; width: 30px; height: 30px; cursor:
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sU66E/2/